# Renaming PATH variable without changing the file name

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, python

I want to add shortcuts for Python 32bit and 64bit to the PATH directory for the command line, one as `python-32` and the other as `python` respectively. What's the easiest way to do this?

I have added `C:\Python27` to the PATH variable, which means it finds `C:\Python27\python.exe` when I type `python` (correctly for my 64bit version). Is there a way I can redirect the `python-32` command to point to `C:\Python27-32\python.exe` or will I have to rename the executable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Renaming an executable can sometimes break something else (e.g. its path may be listed in some scripts or *registry* keys), but if that does not bother you in your case it might just work.

Alternatives to adding python directories to your PATH:

- creating small *scripts* (`.bat` or `.cmd`) in a directory in your PATH; you are free to name those python/python-32 and let them fire up the correct python version (i.e. with full path)
- adding python *shortcuts* (`.lnk`) to a directory in your PATH; you are also free to give those a suitable name, but then you need to explicitly add the `.lnk` extension to your command (unless you register this extension as an executable filename extension like `.exe`, `.com`, `.bat` or `.cmd` –
  see `echo %pathext%`)
- using any smart *launcher* application

Comment: So, I'm trying to make a batch file for the 32bit version. I've added its location to PATH. Now, how do I make it pass its parameters to the python command?

Comment: EDIT: I think this works: I'm using this currently: `@echo off; c:\python27-32\python.exe %*` Will it work in all cases? Is the `%*` usage correct? EDIT: Nvm. I'm nearly 100% sure it will work.

Comment: Instead of `@echo off; c:\…`, you can also just put the `@` in front of the actual command: `@c:\…`.

Comment: Starting python this way will keep your prompt waiting for python to finish. If this is a problem, consider using `start`; explore its options with `help start`.